# docker-compose does not override a command using the start command

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose override file to use for running tests on containers. I want to start my node server with a different command - `nyc node server.js`. I have a docker-compose.coverage.yml file that overrides the normal compose file like so:

```
node:
    command: nyc node server.js
```

However, it never seems to override the command when I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.coverage.yml start node`. When I use `docker-compose run` it overrides the command, but the service exits. Does anyone know why it wouldn't be overriding the command using start?

Comment: I'm thinking that since CMD is part of the built container it's not possible to override it, but run is executing a seperate command in the container regardless of CMD? Just a hunch...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Comment: Since you confirm it worked, I posted it as an answer instead.

Comment: I see you have a risk averse strategy to stack overflow ;)

Comment: Nah, was just pressed for time earlier, threw off a comment instead of properly answering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose start` will start an *existing*, *stopped* container. An existing container will already have the command baked in, and you can't change it.

What you want to do is use `docker-compose up`. This will look for changes to docker-compose.yml, and if there's anything to change, it will recreate the container with the new options, then start or restart it.

So you want something like this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.coverage.yml up -d node
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it'd be nice if you included '--no-recreate' in your answer. Where does it stand?

Comment: @EralpB I'm not sure I understand now `--no-recreate` is of use in this answer; the entire point of the answer is the containers need to be re-created when there have been changes (as opposed to simple restart of the existing container).